Why vert.x jdbc-client version 4.3.0 not compatible with oracle indexes?
I switched from vert.x 3.9.1 to vert.x 4.3.0 and I get this lines in my log.
I should said that everything works but I think new version of jdbc-client ignore CTX Indexes of oracle.
log from server :
Unsupported access properties in SQL metadata
java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException: Unsupported feature: checkValidIndex

could you help find the problem because I can't find good documentation for vert.x jdbc-client.
Version of oracle is 12c

It doesn't seem to be about DB indexes, but checking a bind variable type at a a particular index in a list of variables. This looks similar. That's Spring, but you may be able to avoid the exception by changing how you handle nulls bind values too. You'd need to look at the line in your code that leads to that exception.

unfortunately the exception is not from my code. it comes from inner libraries.

Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with sufficient code to replicate the problem.
